# Is this partial derivative calculation at (0,0) correct?

Tags: real-analysis, calculus, limits, derivatives, partial-derivative

$$f = \left\{ \begin{array}{cc} \frac{xy(x^2-y^2)}{x^2+y^2} & \text{if } (x,y) \neq (0,0); \\ 0 & \text{if } (x,y) = (0,0). \end{array} \right.$$ The first order partial derivative with respect to $x$ is $$\frac{y(x^4+4x^2y^2-y^4)}{(x^2+y^2)^2}$$ which is equal to $-h$ at $(0,h)$ and $0$ at $(0,0)$. To calculate $f_{xy}(0,0)$, we employ the limit definition which is $$f_{xy}(0,0) = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} \frac{f_x(0,h) - f_x(0,0)}{h} = \lim_{h \rightarrow 0} -1 = -1$$ Is this correct?

Comment: Yes, that is correct.

Comment: Thank you for the confirmation

Comment: @JoséCarlosSantos I believe it is wrong. I took $\frac{\partial }{\partial y}(\frac{\partial }{\partial x})$ when it should actually be the other way around

Comment: I am sorry. That's right: what you got is $f_{yx}(0,0)$. Actually, $f_{yx}(0,0)=1$.